# How to plot a graph as a function of two series

Tags: graphite, influxdb, grafana

I want to plot a graph to show %age of user doing transaction on my website. Use case is
  data A - number of user who did transaction on particular day [source - influx]
  data B - number of visitors on a particular day [source elastic]

I want to plot a graph for data A/data B, is it possible in grafana? or is there any workaround?
I googled but couldn't find anything for mixed data sources, but seems like it is possible for graphite.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, Grafana doesn't allow for mixed data sources. You could attempt to store the data entirely in either InfluxDB or Elastic (Or just have some amount of redundant data in each).